# Place buttons between two layouts in android frame layout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-framelayout, android-relativelayout

I am trying to place a RelativeLayout having two ImageButtons inside a FrameLayout which already has a ImageView and a LinearLayout. I have to place the Relative Layout in such a way that vertically upper half of the ImageButton should be overlapping ImageView and lower half overlapping LinearLayout.

My current layout is like this:

[image]

My current xml is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#f2f2f2"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="180dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/fire_icon" />


                <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:background="@color/colorblue"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/title"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Need Help"
                        android:textColor="@color/colortitletext"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/description"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="Hello, I am trying to create a android layout."
                        android:textColor="@color/colorheadtext"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center|right"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView3"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView3"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </FrameLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Expected Layout is:
[image]

Comment: have look on my answer .......

Answer (score 2):

Have look i edit your layout ......

i think that is what you want ..........

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#f2f2f2"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="180dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/fire_icon"/>


                <LinearLayout 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:background="#AACCAA"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/title"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Need Help"
                        android:textColor="@color/colortitletext"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/description"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="Hello, I am trying to create a android layout."
                        android:textColor="@color/colorheadtext"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#f2f2f2"
                android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="200dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"/>


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

enjoy coding...........

Comment: Thank you Sushil. But can this be done without using margins? I mean using some kind of relative positioning to achieve this.

Comment: frame layout working on margin only without margin there is lot problem like phone different pixel, and visibility differ to device to device and etc. I think it is not possible for frame layout without margin set its views.